# Unable to get the markers and location working in android studio google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I'm pretty new to android development and I'm unable to get the current location of gps and display the array of markers on the maps.

Also i'm trying to draw a path with distance and time calculation by following this tutorial in this link: https://javapapers.com/android/draw-path-on-google-maps-android-api/

and how would I send the values of the gps coordinates, distance and duration with a unique id to a firebase realtime database

Where am I going wrong?

```
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Location currentLocation;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE =101;

ArrayList<LatLng>arrayList=new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    LatLng route1 =  new LatLng(-35.016, 143.321);
    LatLng route2 = new LatLng(-34.747, 145.592);
    LatLng route3 = new LatLng(-34.364, 147.891);
    LatLng route4 = new LatLng(-33.501, 150.217);
    LatLng route5 = new LatLng(-32.306, 149.248);
    LatLng route6 = new LatLng(-32.491, 147.309);



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);


        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        arrayList.add(route1);
        arrayList.add(route2);
        arrayList.add(route3);
        arrayList.add(route4);
        arrayList.add(route5);
        arrayList.add(route6);


        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
            return;
        }
        fetchLastLocation();
    }
    private void fetchLastLocation(){
        Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    currentLocation = location;
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,currentLocation.getLatitude()+" "+currentLocation.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment= (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"No Location recorded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(arrayList.get(i)).title("Marker"));

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
            //MarkerOptions are used to create a new Marker.You can specify location, title etc with MarkerOptions
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("You are Here");
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            //Adding the created the marker on the map
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }
        @SuppressLint("NeedOnRequestPermissionsResult")
        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult ( int requestCode, String[] permissions,int[] grantResult){
            switch (requestCode) {
                case LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE:
                    if (grantResult.length > 0 && grantResult[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        fetchLastLocation();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Location permission missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined twice SupportMapFragment please check my code is working fine I have run code and solved the error [image: Please see this image]

```html
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

  
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Location currentLocation;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 101;

    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    LatLng route1 = new LatLng(-35.016, 143.321);
    LatLng route2 = new LatLng(-34.747, 145.592);
    LatLng route3 = new LatLng(-34.364, 147.891);
    LatLng route4 = new LatLng(-33.501, 150.217);
    LatLng route5 = new LatLng(-32.306, 149.248);
    LatLng route6 = new LatLng(-32.491, 147.309);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


        arrayList.add(route1);
        arrayList.add(route2);
        arrayList.add(route3);
        arrayList.add(route4);
        arrayList.add(route5);
        arrayList.add(route6);


        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
            return;
        }
        fetchLastLocation();
    }

    private void fetchLastLocation() {
        Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    currentLocation = location;
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, currentLocation.getLatitude() + " " + currentLocation.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                    mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "No Location recorded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLoaded() {
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position((LatLng) arrayList.get(i)).title("Marker"));
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
                    //MarkerOptions are used to create a new Marker.You can specify location, title etc with MarkerOptions
                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("You are Here");
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,16));
                    //Adding the created the marker on the map
                    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResult) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResult.length > 0 && grantResult[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    fetchLastLocation();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Location permission missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error as "error: cannot find symbol
    private Location currentLocation; "
symbol:   class Location
  location: class MapsActivity

also what about the current location. are you able to get it?

Comment: Hello droid20 I was update my code please check and let me know if you have question I able to get current location in toast message .

Comment: I think there are issues with package imports and dependencies, I'm using the latest gradle plugins, also I've solved it now the code works fine. Is there a way to contact you?

Comment: Yes, Using skype @droid20